# NSKeyedArchiver internal format

Tags: cocoa, format, internal, nskeyedarchiver

Hello I need to load NSKeyedArchiver classes to C++/CLI counterparts. Is there any way to get internal format of NSKeyedArchiver?
Another option is to rewrite whole saving and opening code into pure C++ for both Mac and Windows.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your constraints seem to be:

1. Something easy to parse on both Windows and Mac.
2. 3D modeling data, so the format needs to be efficient

If you want something quick and dirty, go with a binary plist (and possibly gzip it). You could also try [Google's protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) but I have no experience with that. There are also a couple open source implementations of Foundation out there -- [Cocotron](http://cocotron.org/) might be most useful for you.

Comment: I think I will write some quick and dirty custom format in pure C++, using standard ofstream/ifstream in STL. Cocotron looks interesting, if the implementation of format is same with Apple. But I think that reading Cocotron inner workings takes more time than simple ofstream/ifstream C++ implementation for both platforms.

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: I'm about 75% sure it would be the same thing, as I believe NSKeyedArchiver is used in nib files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not serializing anything Objective-C specific then just use XML property lists.

Comment: Problem is that I am serializing modeling data in 3d app, it will be extremely huge in XML.  
So best will be some binary form. I can write serialization in pure C++, but I wrote code using NSKeyedArchiver and if the internal format is not hard I can write similar class for C# or C++/CLI.  

Thanks for fast answer.

Comment: Then there's really not any reason for you to use Apple's format for your data.

Comment: @Azeem.Butt I kinda have the same as he has, and there is a reason, firstly my app was mac only so I used Apple's format now after 3 years I want to pass it to windows. If i want to drop Apple's format I will be in trouble for backward mac compatibility... So maybe I should try with Cocotron :-/